# OpenCV pretrained classifiers for face detection xml files

Tags: c, xml, parsing, opencv, xml-parsing

I am currently working on a face detection project using C language. I have studied abut different algorithms that openCV used for object and face detection. I noticed they have pre-trained data but they are stored in xml files. Will it be possible to read these xml files using C language so I can use it with my face detection program written on C?

Comment: if you aim at reinventing the cascadeclassifier, reading xml will be your *smallest* problem.

Comment: no I don't plan on reinventing. basically i just want to code the detector and then use the xml file to get the threshold values and features